# Iframe tag memory leak

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, memory-leaks

i have the folowing code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <script>
    let removed = false 
    function test (){
      setInterval(() => {
        const myframe= document.getElementById("myframe");
        console.log("asaa")
        if (removed){
          var ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');
          ifrm.setAttribute('id', 'myframe');
          ifrm.setAttribute('src', "");
          document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
          removed = false
          if (bool){
            myframe.src ="./content.html"
          }else{
           myframe.src ="./doco.html"
          }
        }
        else{
          if (bool){
            myframe.src ="./content.html"
        }else{
           myframe.src ="./doco.html"
        }
        }
        bool=!bool
        const iframeWindow = myframe.contentWindow;
        iframeWindow.clearInterval()
        iframeWindow.src = ""
        iframeWindow.clearTimeout()
        document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('myframe'))
        removed = true
  
      },5000)

    }
   
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="test();">
  <h1>xafdsg sdfg sadff f wdf</h1>
  <button onclick="add()">Chnage Mask</button>
  <button onclick="remove()">remove Mask</button>
  <hr>
  <iframe  id="myframe" frameborder= "1"></iframe>
  
</body>
</html>
```

i have an html page with an iframe tag. The content of the iframe is swapped every five seconds. im Order to avoid the iframe memory leak, i delete the iframe and then recreate it, but i get an error in the meantime.
How can i sove that problem?

i getting the follwing error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'src')